# Draw a Poppy in Python 3

Tags: python, drawing, turtle-graphics

My new Python class (age 13) needs a Remembrance Day activity.  We can draw simple shapes with Turtle; does anyone know an easy way of drawing the traditional 2-petal poppy? Thanks!

Comment: What does this traditional 2-petal poppy look like?

Comment: [Check from this site and choose a shape that is similar to what you want](https://www.math10.com/en/geometry/analytic-geometry/geometry5/special-plane-curves.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help; the Cardioid is closest to the shape of the poppies you buy to wear on Remembrance Day....but I don't know how to write Python code that uses polar co-ordinates.  You would need to draw 2 of them (one facing left to right and the other right to left) and then add a black circle in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cardioid is closest to the shape of the poppies you buy to wear on
>   Remembrance Day. ... You would need to draw 2 of them (one facing left
>   to right and the other right to left) and then add a black circle ...

How does this look?  It's a couple of generic cardioids and a circle arranged to look like a poppy:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import pi, sin, cos

def cardioid(turtle, k):
    origin_x, origin_y = turtle.position()
    theta = 0.0

    turtle.begin_fill()

    while theta < 2.0 * pi:
        x = 2 * k * (1 - cos(theta)) * cos(theta)
        y = 2 * k * (1 - cos(theta)) * sin(theta)

        turtle.goto(origin_x + x, origin_y + y)
        theta += 0.1

    turtle.end_fill()

screen = Screen()

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience
yertle.color('red')

for sign in [-1, 1]:
    yertle.penup()
    yertle.setx(sign * 100)
    yertle.pendown()

    cardioid(yertle, sign * 30)

yertle.penup()
yertle.home()
yertle.dot(80, 'black')

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant!  Thank you so, so much.  I haven't used the import Math option before, so this is the magic trick I need.